# Is there a difference between spring fatigue and plastic deformation in springs?

Tags: material-science, spring, stress-strain

Is there a difference between spring fatigue and plastic deformation in springs? Plastic deformation means permanent deformation in springs caused due to stretching in springs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plastic deformation is largely due to dislocation motion and is a more general term in materials science.

That out of the way I think I still understand your question.

In general:

plastic deformation occurs when a material is stressed beyond it's yield stress. (this can be in tension, compression, or torsion)

Fatigue failure occurs due to continually being put under stress, and relieved, without necessarily going anywhere close to the yield stress.

In a perfectly machined material fatigue failure would, theoretically, never occur because it tends to start at imperfections on the surface e.g. cracks, grooves, etc. While plastic deformation could still occur because it depends almost solely on bond strength.

Springs are good examples for fatigue because that is exactly what they do. However if used properly (i.e. not over stretching) they won't experience plastic deformation in the traditional sense.